# performance wise: running photoshop cs6 on wine is same as on windows?

Tags: ubuntu, wine, window

I got bored of windows, the viruses, slowdown of system over time.
I would like to switch to ubuntu, wanted to by emulating photoshop on wine, is the performance of photoshop is as fast of windows? any lags?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Wine wiki. There is a topic specifically about this exact question, titled: [Running Adobe Photoshop on Wine](http://wiki.winehq.org/AdobePhotoshop).

For CS6 there doesn't appear to be any info. Searching a bit more I found this AskUbuntu Q&A titled: [Installing Photoshop CS5 on Ubuntu 12.10 using Wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214675/installing-photoshop-cs5-on-ubuntu-12-10-using-wine), which guided me to this link back into the Wine project's site, [App DB](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=17).

Looking through that page there was a link to CS6, [Adobe Photoshop > CS6 (13.0)](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25607). The tests performed using Wine + CS6 are summarized there. Here are the general take aways:

#### What works

- Selection tools, path tools, brush, zoom, Edit/File/Window menu. 90% stuff works, didnt face anything bad yet.

#### What does not

- Brush hold and drawing

So I would try it but I'm not sure I would expect it to work flawlessly. I would expect it to work OK, and you'll likely get frustrated with it and want to either do one of the following things:

1. Switch to something else that runs natively, such as GIMP
2. Setup a virtual machine (VM) of Windows and run it inside there

My experience with Wine is that, it's a well intentioned project, but it generally doesn't work well enough for day to day use of apps such as CS6.

Comment: Is ther a free VM which has GPU acceleration enabled?